# View Controller only Protocol has no access to View Controller properties

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIViewController` only protocol

```swift
protocol VCProtocol where Self: UIViewController {}
```

I have a function with `VCProtocol` parameter. Inside the function I can not access any property of `UIViewController`

```swift
func testFunction(vcProtocol: VCProtocol) {
    // vcProtocol.view  ‼️ error: Value of type 'VCProtocol' has no member 'view'
}
```

Though I can cast the protocol parameter to `UIViewController` and then access the property like this:

```swift
func testFunction(vcProtocol: VCProtocol) {
    (vcProtocol as! UIViewController).view
}
```

Is this is the way? Do we have any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is now supported properly from [**Swift 5**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_beta_4_release_notes/swift_5_release_notes_for_xcode_10_2_beta_4). You can try it Xcode 10.2 beta 4. For older versions, you would have to resort to [@Ricky Mo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10317684/ricky-mo)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55292766/7734643).

```
protocol VCProtocol: UIViewController {

    func testFunction(vcProtocol: VCProtocol)

}

class A: UIViewController, VCProtocol {

    func testFunction(vcProtocol: VCProtocol) {
        debugPrint(vcProtocol.view)
    }

}
```

---

From the notes,

> Protocols can now constrain their conforming types to those that
>   subclass a given class. Two equivalent forms are supported:
>
> ```
> protocol MyView: UIView { /*...*/ } 
>
> protocol MyView where Self: UIView { /*...*/ }
> ```
>
> Swift 4.2 accepted the second form, but it wasn’t fully implemented
>   and could sometimes crash at compile time or runtime. ([SR-5581](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5581))
>   (38077232)

Comment:  The whole point of the question was what is logically seems so obvious is not there. Thanks for the findings.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `&` operator to combine protocols

```
protocol VCProtocol where Self: UIViewController {}

func testFunction(vcProtocol: VCProtocol & UIViewController) {
    let view = vcProtocol.view
}
```

Comment: Why? When the protocol already is restricted to `UIViewController`s' ?

Comment: When you treat the object as a protocol implementation, you cannot see its members beyond that protocol declared. That's what protocol meant to do.

Comment: @RickyMo  I thing it is better than casting

Comment: Yes. Exactly. And the protocol here is restricted to `UIViewController`. So, you will be able to see anything that you normally see in a `UIViewController`

Comment: @RakeshaShastri You can't, or at least I can't in my Xcode.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri You can use `self.view`  within `extension VCProtocol{}`, but not anywhere outside. Outside `VCProtocol`, users of `VCProtocol` know nothing more than the `VCProtocol`'s declared members (this is what `protocol` means). They are not supposed to know that `VCProtocol` must be `UIViewController`. You just prevent other class from implementing that protocol dose not mean that protocol inherit anything from that specific class.

Comment: _"They are not supposed to know only `VCProtocol` must be `UIViewController`"_. **Wrong**. They are supposed to know this. That is the whole point. _"You just restrict other class from implementing that protocol dose not mean that protocol inherit anything from that specific class."_ The protocol never inherits anything. The protocol works only in the case it is inherited by a `UIViewController` and never otherwise. That is the whole point. So there is absolutely no reason why it shouldn't show `UIViewController` properties.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Maybe you could request this feature from the Swift team?

Comment: @RickyMo It is already there in Xcode 10.2 beta 4. Seems like they refined it for Swift 5.